# Использование smarty функций с json

Tags: php, javascript, jquery, json, smarty

Пытаюсь сделать infinite scroll, с php, smarty и jquery ajax. Как я понял, для того, чтоб не нагружать сильно сервер идеально осуществлять весь процесс на клиентской части и получать ответ в формате json. Проблема в том, что мне необходимо использовать функции движка smarty.
Немного кода, чтоб вы поняли, что я имею в виду:

```
$.each(data.content, function(key, value ){
if(value.comment !=''){

//Что касается даты, то smarty здесь работает и можно использовать date_format
html += '<div class="timeline-date"><i class="fa fa-calendar"></i> 
{'+value.date+'|date_format:"%B %d, %Y %I:%M %p"}</div>';
html += '</div>';

//Но вот с функциями, беда
html += '<p>{'+value.comment+'|smarty_modifier_autolink|nl2br|mention}</p>';
}
}
```

В браузере, все, что я получаю -  `+value.comment+` вместо самого комментария.
Я не дружу с `json` или `javascript-ом` может есть еще, какой нибудь способ рендерить json, чтоб можно было использовать `smarty` функции? Буду рад любому совету или подсказке! Всем большое спасибо!

Comment: > Smarty - компилирующий обработчик шаблонов 
Шаблоны он компилирует на сервере. В браузере у вас функционал smarty недоступен. То есть если вы аяксом делаете свой запрос, то smarty функции не отработают

Comment: Да, я сдался уже, буду по другому все переделывать. Спасибо!

Comment: вам именно json надо получать? Тут уж либо вернуть JSON и сформировать все на js, либо вернуть частичный html, для которого на сервере вы используете смарти, и добавляете вывод к своей странице. Есть еще вариант, сгенерить html с помощью смарти, запихать его в с JSON в виде строкового поля и вернуть. Но как по мне, то JSON  вам тут не нужен, а нужна классическая подгрузка html-контента через ajax.

Comment: Ну вот, я по классике сейчас все и переделываю, но хотелось json так как меня убедили, что это отличный способ не нагружать сервер и бд

Comment: нагрузка на БД то не изменится никак, хоть в json вы данные выдадите хоть html-сгенерите, данные то все равно в БД запрашиваете одинаковые.

Comment: А вообще да, все равно придется каждый раз обращаться за новой порцией комментариев в бд, и чего это я сам не сообразил а слушаю товарищей из туториалов всяких.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Не знаю какой движок вы используете, если испольузете, и как именно вы используете `smarty`. Но вот такой пример, возможно он будет несколько в виде "псевдокода".

Допустим, вы на странице прокручиваете комментарии. и в какой то момент, вам нужно запросить у сервера новую порцию данных. Сервер вам возвращает некоторый объект `data` (судя по вашему коду). В этом объекте есть `data.content` - сведения комментах (ну или еще чем-нибудь). Видимо помимо данного поля, там имеются и другие поля, может быть `data.count` с количеством комментариев, и т.п.

вариант, как это можно устроить следующий:
у вас имеется скрипт `ajax_comments.php` (либо это метод контроллера, или еще что-нибудь, в зависимости от архитектуры). Данный скрипт генерирует этот объект `$data`.

```
$comments = Comments->find()   // условное получение части комментов из БД
                    ->where(['published' => 1])
                    ->toArray(); 

// ваши данные
$data = [
           'content' => null, 
           'count' => count($comments),
           .... // еще какие-то поля
        ]; 


$smarty = new Smarty();
// передали данные в шаблон 
$smarty->assign('comments', $comments);
// получили вывод шаблона в переменную
$data['content'] = $smarty->fetch('comments.tpl');

// упаковали все в JSON. вывод шаблона в виде строки
echo json_encode($data);
exit;
```

ваш шаблон для комментариев `comments.tpl`, будет примерно следующий (не очень ясна структура):

```
{foreach $comments as $c}
    <div class="timeline-date">
        <i class="fa fa-calendar"></i> 
        {$c.date|date_format:"%B %d, %Y %I:%M %p"} 
    </div>
    <div>
       <p>{$c.comment|nl2br}</p>
    </div> 
{/foreach}
```

Ваш ajax-запрос к серверу для получения новой порции комментариев, должен быть примерно такой:

```
$.post("ajax_comments.php", { ... параметры ...}, function(data){
   // делаете что-то с дополнительными данными
   alert(data.count);

   // добавляете комментарии к странице
   $("#comments").append(data.content);
});
```

Comment: Спасибо за Ваш ответ! В качестве гайда я использовал следующий туториал - http://www.smarttutorials.net/infinite-scroll-using-jquery-ajax-php-and-mysql/. Здесь даны два способа бесконечного скроллинга с помощью json и с прямым обращением к серверу. Я немного заблудился в Вашем ответе, но если Вы наведете меня на то, как я смогу использовать json и smarty и не нагружать сервер, я буду очень благодарен, и  отмечу Ваш ответ принятым.

Comment: @JohnnyCatsville дак вроде у меня тут 3 блока кода приведены, один пхп, другой smarty-шаблон, третий js код.

Comment: Все верно, я уже разобрался. Спасибо большое!